Removable Storage - Removable Drives not executed after upgrade 22.04 to 24.04
After the release upgrade 22.04 to 24.04, the earlier 'auto'-mounted external drives (Settings in System Settings -> Removable Drives; KDE) are still set in System Settings to mount at start (what they invariably did in 22.04), but none is actually mounted at start after the release upgrade.
Mounting can easily be done later manually, but, reproducible, is never done at startup.
(Don't tell me, this was a bug. I had filed it as such, under #2078571. It was thrown out as 'invalid', and I was told to ask here, how to solve it.)
